# Handlebar content dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

**I have the code below that should display the chat window when I click on the user name in**  `<li>`

**Code `<ul>` which contains the User list and received the click**

```
<ul class="chat-contacts">
  <li class="online" data-user-id="USERCODE">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body">
          <div class="contact-name">USERNAME</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**This is the chat window code. If I put a static content of the `<ul>` window appears, however when I feed the the `<ul>` with content dynamic the click does not work. Can someone help me??**

```
<script id="chat-window-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"  data-toggle="chat-collapse" data-target="#chat-bill">
      <a href="#" class="close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="pull-left">
            <img src="{{ user_image }}" width="40">
        </span>
        <span class="contact-name">{{user}}</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="chat-bill">
    </div>
        <form id="messageForm">
            <input id="nameInput" type="hidden" class="input-medium" value="Macbook" />
            <input id="messageInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite uma mensagem" />
        </form>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the JS code too?

Answer (score 0):

Your click event is not working. The event doesn't know the element exists.

This can happen when using `jQuery('.chat-contacts li').click(function(){// do something})`

I would try setting the click event with this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.chat-contacts li', function(){

});
```

Setting the event with `on` will force jQuery to scan for new elements in the list.